# Входят ли ошибки компилляции java в класс Throwable?

Tags: java, исключения, компиляция

Есть иерархия исключений `java`, на вершине которой стоит класс `Throwable`.

**Вопрос:** является ли ошибка компиляции (к примеру я не поставил точку с запятой где надо) объектом класса `Throwable`? Если ошибка компиляции не является объектом класса `Throwable`, объект какого класса кидает нам IDE при компилляции некорректного текста программы?

Comment: Это интерфейс...

Comment: Да, является...

Comment: @Miron я может многого не понимаю, но имхо JRE кидает нам объект. Есть объект - значит есть конкретный класс. Throwable не интерфейс по мнению Oracle https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка компиляции может являться объектом класса `Throwable`. А может и не являться. Всё зависит от конкретной реализации компилятора.

Представим компилятор как чёрную коробку с прорезью, которая принимает java-файлы, а выдаёт class-файлы, или сообщение об ошибке компиляции. Что находится внутри коробки?

- Если компилятор реализован на java, сообщения об ошибках могут быть результатом работы механизма исключений, а могут и не быть. Можно посмотреть исходники OpenJDK. Для этого нужно иметь представление об этапах компиляции: лексический разбор, синтаксический разбор и т.д.
- Вообще, компилятор может быть реализован на каком-нибудь другом языке, тогда к исключениям Java он не будет иметь вообще никакого отношения.

Как бы то ни было, механизм выдачи ошибок компиляции никак не связан с вашей программой, которую вы компилируете. Если компилятор и бросает исключение, оно обрабатывается внутри компилятора, а вы получаете только результат -- строку с сообщением об ошибке.

Также механизм выдачи ошибок компилятора не связан с IDE. IDE может просто показывать вам сообщение, полученное от компилятора. Или может самостоятельно проверять код до запуска компилятора и показывать ошибки каким-то ещё способом (например, подчёркивать красным).

Comment: Ну ваш ответ местами выглядит очень даже здраво, с одним но - у меня есть подозрения, что все компиляторы java должны подчинятся какой-то спецификации. В контексте этой спецификации (я допускаю) все ошибки которые мы получаем в строке (типа java 25:syntax error) могут быть унаследованы от Throable. 
То, что механизм компиляции, как вы пишите, не связан с компилируемой программой - это всем понятно, но он может быть связан со спецификацией языка java.

Comment: То, что мы с вами можем, выпив литр, написать компилятор, который никаким спецификациям не подчиняется - мне это вполне понятно. И там действительно выдаваемые строки - будут не унаследованы ни от чего. 
Но с другой стороны, мы также можем написать компилятор так, что выдаваемые ошибки будут унаследованы и от error, и от Throawable, и от Exception и от любого другого (не финального) класса. Это тоже ясно. Значит нужно, с моей стороны, наверное уточнить - javac реализован как??

Comment: Ладно, постановим компромисс:  ошибка компиляции зависит от реализации компилятора.

Comment: Исходный код должен соответствовать спецификации языка Java, чтобы называться программой на Java. Скомпилированный должен соответствовать спецификации JVM, чтобы выполняться на ней. А кому может быть должен компилятор, который делает из одного другое?

Comment: Компилятор выдаёт сообщение об ошибке в виде строки. Это можно сделать и без исключений. Чтобы разобраться, как сделано, можно посмотреть исходники OpenJDK.

Answer (score 0):

[Да является](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html). Класс `Error` наследует класс `Throwable`, часть ошибок `Error` конкретно описаны как:

> That is, Error and its subclasses are regarded as unchecked exceptions for the purposes of compile-time checking of exceptions.
>
> Таким образом Error и его подклассы рассматриваются как непроверяемые исключения для целей проверки исключений во время компиляции.

Comment: Вы неправильно истолковали приведённое предложение. Прочитайте про checked и unchecked исключения. Ошибки компиляции логически никак не связаны с исключениями Java. Компилятор из java-файлов в class-файлы может быть написан на любом языке, и может ничего не знать про джавовские исключения. При этом, если вы забудете точку с запятой в конце строки, то это будет ошибкой компиляции на этапе синтаксического разбора.

Comment: Дайте развёрнутый ответ. Я проверю, сниму галку и поставлю вам.

Comment: Любые исключения в вашей программе могут возникнуть только тогда, когда ваша программа выполняется. Чтобы выполнить программу, сначала нужно её скомпилировать. Error и его наследники -- это те ошибки, восстановление от которых не предполагается. То есть программа завершает свою работу. Эти ошибки рассматривают как unchecked при компиляции, чтобы не загромождать код throws Error или try-catch, так как они могут возникнуть практически где угодно. Например, OutOfMemoryError может возникнуть, грубо говоря, при создании любого объекта, если виртуальная машина не может выделить под него память.